# Java Login Username on Remote Machine

Tags: java, sockets

I'm working on a very simple file sharing program in LAN networks using Java. The software uses Socket ans ServerSocket classes to send and receive to/from machines which user knows the IP addresses of.
I want to improve the software in a way that user can enter the other's machine username instead of IP, for example if the user of the other machine which is trying to connect to this machine is a specific username, so the connection is allowed.

Comment: Just a thought: When I stated my server based application, I looked into sockets to and found it was a lot a tedious work compared to RMI. Also I think RMI might support machine name also.

Comment: What do you mean by username? Netbios name under windows, hostname, domain name or something else?

Comment: I mean the username of the currently logged in user on that machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be maintaining some form of `username -> IP (or hostname)` mapping. This could be done by a DHCP server, but that's a bit of a overkill (or impossible if you cannot set up a DHCP server), so I recommend your program maintains a mapping itself.

To build the mapping, you could try this: When a host goes up, it could send a LAN broadcast message with its username to notify its presence. Upon receiving the notifications, the other hosts would register sender host's IP and username, then answer with their respective user names and IP addresses.

Comment: Wow, it is an intelligent solution, I may go for implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You got to make separate application that will run on computer that is always on and will keep list of IPs associated with Usernames. Your file sharing application will connect to that "server" asking for username and in return it will return IP that your filesharing app use to connect to other computer.